# How to route copied packets to second interface?

Tags: networking, centos, routing, iptables, amazon-web-services

I have two AWS instances running CentOS 7, A and B, and I need to send all copied packets from A to a second interface on B (`eth1`). I have set up IPTables to copy and send packets:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j TEE --gateway 10.0.3.101
```

I can see the packets increment using:

```
iptables -t mangle -L -n -v
```

I can ping both interfaces from each other. The route is set up as:

```
default via 10.0.3.1 dev eth1 table 100
10.0.3.100 dev eth1 table 100
```

The rules are set as:

```
from 10.0.3.100 lookup table 100
to 10.0.3.101 lookup table 100
```

When I do a tcpdump for eth1, I only get ARP request and reply. When I ping from `10.0.3.100` to `10.0.3.101`, I can see the ICMP packets.

Source/destination check is disabled. `ip_forward` is enabled on both instances.

With a single interface set up on an instance in the same subnet, I can see the copied packets. When I set up an instance with two interfaces, in two different subnets, I can not see any copied packets, but I can see pings and responses to them on both instances.

- Instance A has `eth0` on `10.0.3.100` (subnet `10.0.3.0/24`).
- Instance B has eth0 on `10.0.4.100` (subnet `10.0.4.0/24`) and 
  eth1 on `10.0.3.101` (subnet `10.0.3.1/24`).
- I am trying to send copied packets from `10.0.3.100` to `10.0.3.101`.

Answer (score 0):

Since this was on AWS, I didn't disable source and destination check on the second interface. After correcting that, it worked.